# Can I determine the channel name for each entry within a relationship field tag pair?

Tags: relationships

On a relationship field that allows user to select entries from multiple channels, is it possible on the front end template to use the entry’s channel name in a conditional? Like I want to use different html and display different fields depending on whether the entry is from channel A or B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the single channel variables to do something like this...

```
{home_slideshow status="open|featured"}
    {if "{home_slideshow:channel_short_name}" == "channel_events"}
```

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/entries.html#single-variables

Comment: That worked, thanks!